# why this query is failing?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is failing:

```
 INSERT INTO sportman
   (image) 
 VALUES
   ('/res/(1)(38).jpg') 
 WHERE sportman_code = '1';
```

`image` is text and `sportman_code` is char(20).

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't support WHERE clauses using this particular syntax.  You wouldn't be inserting data if it already exists ;)

Comment: hi mehdi i dont think insert statement can be used to update. Instead you can try this query : update sportman set image ='/res/(1)(38).jpg' where sportman_code = '1';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `WHERE` clause with `INSERT` query remove that part

```
 insert into sportman(image) values('/res/(1)(38).jpg')
```

if you are looking to update record use update query instead

```
UPDATE sportman
   SET image='/res/(1)(38).jpg'
 WHERE sportman_code = '1';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for UPDATE instead

```
UPDATE sportman 
SET `image`='/res/(1)(38).jpg' 
WHERE sportman_code = '1';
```

Comment: how this is a correct query? column name is image, and you are using it with table name.

Answer (score 1):

This query is failing because there's not supposed to be a `WHERE` clause on an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
update sportman set image= '/res/(1)(38).jpg'  where sportman_code = '1';
```

you need a update query not insert query, if you are updating existing record.

Or

to insert new record

```
INSERT INTO sportman (image,sportman_code) 
VALUES ('/res/(1)(38).jpg', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert doesn't have a WHERE syntax.

Try this one:

```
INSERT INTO sportman 
            (image, 
             sportman_code) 
VALUES     ('/res/(1)(38).jpg', 
            '1');
```

Or do with an UPDATE query

```
UPDATE sportman 
SET    image = '/res/(1)(38).jpg' 
WHERE  sportman_code = '1';
```